# 404 page url in magento 2

Tags: magento2, redirect, 404-page

I am using Magento version 2.1.3 for my website.

We are getting the correct 404 page while accessing the non-existing url.
But I need to redirect the url to "/404" as well for the magento 404 page.

For Example:
I have accessed my website with "/abc" and getting 404 page but the url remains same as
www.domain.com/abc

I need to redirect the url to "/404" instead of getting the same url("/abc") what we have typed for every 404 Pages.

www.domain.com/abc should redirect to www.domain.com/404 if it is non existing url.

Please can any one suggest a best solution for this...

Please advise, 
Sandra

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by creating a module as follows.

Create a new module and add these files:

1) `Your\Module\Controller\NoRouteHandler.php`

```
<?php

namespace Your\Module\Controller;


use Magento\Framework\App\Router\NoRouteHandlerInterface;

class NoRouteHandler implements NoRouteHandlerInterface
{
    public function process(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $request->setModuleName('404')->setControllerName('redirect')->setActionName('index');
    }
}
```

Here we are creating a new `NoRouteHandler` that will be used instead of the default Magento one that uses the `cms/noroute/index` controller. We want to use a custom controller instead, in this case, `404/redirect/index`.

2) `Your/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\Router\NoRouteHandlerList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="handlerClassesList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="redirect404" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Your\Module\Controller\NoRouteHandler</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

This adds our handler to the `NoRouteHandlerList` collection, placing it before the default Magento one by using a sort order of 20.

Now we need to declare a new route:

3) `Your\Module\etc\frontend\routes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="404" frontName="404">
            <module name="Your_Module"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

We need two controllers, the first controller is

4) `Your\Module\Controller\Redirect\Index.php`

```
<?php

namespace Your\Module\Controller\Redirect;


use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Index extends Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_redirect('404');
    }
}
```

This controller redirects to the "/404" url which corresponds to our other controller shown below which simply forwards to the `cms\noroute\index` controller.

5) `Your\Module\Controller\Index\Index.php`

```
namespace AAllen\Test\Controller\Index;


use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Index extends Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_forward('index', 'noroute', 'cms');
    }
}
```

With this module in place, 404 pages will have the "/404" URL instead of whatever the user entered.

Answer (score 3):

Add a rewrite to your webserver or vhost configuration. How that is done is easily searched via Google for your webserver, which is likely Apache or Nginx.