# How can I redirect 404 page to home page?

Tags: magento2, 404, home, not-found

Can anyone let me know how can I **redirect 404** page to the homepage?
I want to redirect any not found page to home page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .htaccess with something along these lines.

`ErrorDocument 404 http://generalautostore.com/`

In your magento .htaccess look for ['ErrorDocument 404 /pub/errors/404.php'](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/.htaccess#L279) and replace the '/pub/errors/404.php' bit with your url or simply `/` for site root.

More info here: http://www.htaccessbasics.com/404-custom-error-page/

If still in trouble, maybe this will help: [404 page url in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154711/404-page-url-in-magento-2)